# ActionBarSherlock - Submenu / Popup menu in custom bottom bar

Tags: android, popup, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, submenu

I'm using an `IcsLinearLayout` in my view at the bottom that has buttons like the follwoing in it (I'm just styling them like action buttons)

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btSelectAll"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/abs__item_background_holo_dark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/holo_dark_content_select_all" />
```

and I now would like to add a submenu button, that's looking and working like the sub menu button in the actionbar...

How could I achieve that?